# Who is responsible for the creation of Earth, Lord Shiva or Adhishakti?

Tags: shiva, creation, shakti, earth

Who is responsible for the creation of Earth, Lord Shiva or Adhishakti?

Comment: Both. They are not separated.  Ardhanarishvara!

Comment: It depends on which purnana you read.

Comment: As per kashmir shaivaism everyone are shiva shakti. !!!! Shiva shakti are in everyone and everywhere! So you canmot separate them like a dance cannot be separated from dancer

Comment: This is not at all opinion based question! One can answer both are one from scriptural references. I would have if I had verses with me!!!

Comment: Voted to Reopen the Question as it doesnt generate Opinion based answers!

Answer (score 4):

Lord Shiva can not create alone without the help of Adi Shakti. This is the essence of various scriptures.

Adi Shankaracharya's [Soundarya Lahiri](http://www.astrojyoti.com/soundaryalahari.htm) mentions this at the very beginning:

> Shivah shakthya yukto yadi bhavati shaktah prabhavitum
>  Na chedevam
>   devo na khalu kusalah spanditumapi;
>  Atas tvam aradhyam
>   Hari-Hara-Virinchadibhir api
>  Pranantum stotum vaa katham
>   akrta-punyah prabhavati
>
> **Lord Shiva, only becomes able. To do creation in this world. along
>   with Shakthi Without her, Even an inch he cannot move,** And so how can,
>   one who does not do good deeds, Or one who does not sing your praise,
>   Become adequate to worship you Oh , goddess mine, Who is worshipped by
>   the trinity.

However, in Hinduism we have the concept of the [Trinity - Brahma (creator), Vishnu (preserver) and Mahesawra (destroyer)](https://sites.google.com/a/pleasantonusd.net/hindu-gods/hindu-trinity). So, usually creation comes under Lord Brahma's duties.

Comment: It seems to me that Adi Shakti and God Shiva are the same. Am I wrong? Where can i read more about this?

Comment: Yes that is correct. When Shiva and the Goddess are united that is when they are able to create. The innermost bindu (the dot) of the Sri Yantra represents Shiva (in the Kameswara form) + Shakti (Lalita Tripurasundari). These things are dealt with in the Tantras and are somewhat complicated to understand. @Random-15 If you know about the seven Chakras in our body, the highest Chakra-Sahsrara is presided by a combined form of Shiva+Shakti known as the Ardhanariswara.

Comment: You can read some basic things from here: http://www.shivashakti.com/tripura.htm @Random-15